# Gmail Login issue with Mozilla browser

Tags: gmail, mozilla

I login into the my gmail account on the mozilla firefox after that I just close the browser whenever I again open the same browser and open my gmail account it open directly without user and password so I want to know this information are stored where?

Comment: This is not a programming question I am voting this as off topic. One simple answer cookies and sessions

Comment: I know its not a programming question but its a related to IT thatswhy I asked the question.

Comment: It is a large domian. Here you should only ask programming question your question is a general computing related. I would suggest take a tour at stackoverflow and also earn your first badge

Answer (score 0):

it stores in cookies. for more info read this link: 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-are-my-logins-stored